# Hidden Service on Qubes Whonix, can not access Onion site from browser

Tags: onion-services, whonix, qubes

I am trying to set up a hidden service on Qubes on the gateway with the server on a workstation. I followed the Whonix guide and checked to ensure the configuration was valid and that I could get the lighttpd page to load when I called curl [workstation_ip]:80. When I use another Qubes Workstation to try to access the service I get "The connection was reset". iptables looks like it should according to the tutorial.

Comment: So you're using the qubes templates?  Installing qubes on a server sounds cumbersome,  https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Qubes/Install